# Adicionar elementos via JavaScript a partir do banco de dados

Tags: javascript, php

Estou utilizando um efeito de *Full Screen Overlay* em [meu site](http://www.planow.com.br/jrgrill/dicas.php), este efeito eu peguei no [Codrops](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/02/06/fullscreen-overlay-effects/). Ele está funcionando normal, porém, como estou buscando dados no BD, como fazer ele funcionar não só em um botão, mas como vários?

**JS**:

```
(function() {
var triggerBttn = document.getElementById('menudrops'),
    overlay = document.querySelector( 'div.overlay' ),
    closeBttn = overlay.querySelector( 'p.overlay-close' );
    transEndEventNames = {
        'WebkitTransition': 'webkitTransitionEnd',
        'MozTransition': 'transitionend',
        'OTransition': 'oTransitionEnd',
        'msTransition': 'MSTransitionEnd',
        'transition': 'transitionend'
    },
    transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transition' ) ],
    support = { transitions : Modernizr.csstransitions };
    s = Snap( overlay.querySelector( 'svg' ) ), 
    path = s.select( 'path' ),
    steps = overlay.getAttribute( 'data-steps' ).split(';'),
    stepsTotal = steps.length;

function toggleOverlay() {
    if( classie.has( overlay, 'open' ) ) {
        var pos = stepsTotal-1;
        classie.remove( overlay, 'open' );
        classie.add( overlay, 'close' );

        var onEndTransitionFn = function( ev ) {
                classie.remove( overlay, 'close' );
            },
            nextStep = function( pos ) {
                pos--;
                if( pos < 0 ) return;
                path.animate( { 'path' : steps[pos] }, 60, mina.linear, function() { 
                    if( pos === 0 ) {
                        onEndTransitionFn();
                    }
                    nextStep(pos);
                } );
            };

        nextStep(pos);
    }
    else if( !classie.has( overlay, 'close' ) ) {
        var pos = 0;
        classie.add( overlay, 'open' );

        var nextStep = function( pos ) {
            pos++;
            if( pos > stepsTotal - 1 ) return;
            path.animate( { 'path' : steps[pos] }, 60, mina.linear, function() { nextStep(pos); } );
        };

        nextStep(pos);
    }
    }

    triggerBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
    closeBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
})();
```

**PHP**:

```
<section>
    <p id="menudrops">'.$titulo.'</p>
</section>
```

Comment: O seu link mostra uma página com `DESCULPE, ESSA PÁGINA NÃO EXISTE`. Pode ser mais claro na pergunta explicando o efeito que quer? vi o outro link também mas não percebí qual o efeito que você quer. Coloque o seu código aqui também para podermos ajudar.

Comment: @Sergio esta alterado o link, o efeito que eu quero é este : http://tympanus.net/Development/FullscreenOverlayStyles/index12.html clicando no botao "open overlay" ele faz a animacao, no meu caso eh o texto embaixo da foto, quando clicar no link ele faz este efieto, so que ele funciona apenas uma vez

Comment: pra esse efeito você precisa desse plugin? não é mais fácil criar um campo com display none com o conteúdo que você quer apresentar na tela e depois dar um fade com js? você teria o mesmo efeito de forma dinâmica, poderia controlar mais fácil o conteúdo e os gatilhos para ativar esse efeito

Comment: Você tem o mesmo ID em todos os elementos... ID's são unicas, não podem ser duplicadas.

Comment: @RodrigoBorth mas teria que ter aquele efeito, subir e ampliar, como daria pra fazer?

Comment: você pode fazer com animate, coloque possition absolute e bottom 0; entao de um animate para height 100% e junte com um fadein que vai ficar o mesmo efeito

Comment: foda que nao tenho conhecimento em js, vc pode me ajudar a montar no jsfiddle ?

Comment: na verdade acho que você nao podera usar o fadein e o animate ao mesmo tempo, mas pode usar o animate ja que o fundo tem opacidade o efeito fica bem parecido

Comment: vou ver se consigo montar um rapido aqui e te mando

Comment: ok, vlw @RodrigoBorth

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZPjxu/1/

Comment: no js fiddle nao funciona, mas se passar pra um arquivo você poderá ver funcionando

Comment: e tambem ficou bem simples de entender a lógica

Comment: nao consegui rodar

Comment: como falei, no fiddle nao funciona pois ele nao aceita, alguns atributos do CSS como position por exemplo, coloquei a resposta, passa ela pra um arquivo que você vai conseguir rodar de boa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso de outra forma, sem usar o plugin

A minha alternativa pra isso seria usar uma div com display none e overflow hidden e no momento do click dar um animate na altura dela...

Seguem os codigos de exemplo

HTML

```
<div class='Efeito'>
        coloque o conteudo aqui
    </div>
<a class="ativarefeito" href='javascript:void(0)'>Clique para ativa o efeito</a>
```

CSS

```
.Efeito{position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; background: red; width: 100%; height: 0; z-index: 9999; opacity: 0.5; overflow: hidden;}
```

Javascript

```
$(function(){
    $('.ativarefeito').click(function(){
        $('.Efeito').animate({
            height: '100%'
        });
    });
});
```

Trabalhando um pouco o código você pode fazer o efeito surgir do ponto que você quiser, até mesmo a partir do centro indo em direção as pontas, esse é apenas o exemplo mais simples que pude fazer, utilizei algo parecido nessa pagina:
http://wja.inf.br/Parceiros

Comment: http://pastebin.com/m5XnG0mq
eu nao to conseguindo

Comment: eu consegui no CodePen